# Remove space in the default `\cref` command

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, cleveref

I have my `crefs` defined as

```
\crefname{section}{§}{§}
\crefname{subsection}{§§}{§§}
```

And when I reference it displays, for example, like § 4.5. I would like the middle space to dissapear and this works perfectly

```
\crefname{section}{§\hspace*{-0.1cm}}{§\hspace*{-0.1cm}}
\crefname{subsection}{§§\hspace*{-0.1cm}}{§§\hspace*{-0.1cm}}
```

displaying §4.5. However, this seems like really dirty for some reason. Is there a better or more clean way to acomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define the format of your reference using `\crefformat{<type>}{<format>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{section}{§#2#1#3}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:mysection}
\cref{sec:mysection}

\end{document}
```

For more details on the layout choices for `<format>`, see section **8.2.1 Single Cross-References** of the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf).

Comment: Use `\crefformat{section}{#2§#1#3}` to make the § sign part of the link if using hyperref

Comment: @Atnas What about equations? I use `\crefformat{equation}{#2Eq.(#1)#3}`, however it doesn't work; an error will be reported.

Comment: @SJH: No problem here, with [this MWE](https://pastebin.com/raw/iq4peqHW).

Comment: This isn't quite enough as it won't handle the plural cases, e.g. "sections 3.1 and 3.2"